# How do I use jsonschema indirect enumsource for extended choice parameter?

Tags: json, jenkins, jsonschema

I'm using the Jenkins Extended Choice Parameter plugin which depends on json-editor https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor (originally by J. Dorn)

I want to present two drop-down list boxes, one with the choice:

- alpha
- beta
- release

and the other with a list of git branches dependent on the first choice.

Using groovy I can get the git branches and sort them into three arrays: `alpha`, `beta`, and `release` but I'm not sure how to poke those into the `jsonEditorOptions` so that they can be an `enumSource` and update the second list box.

My poor attempt below ensures that something changes in the second list box, but only the individual letters (restricted to 1 item with slice) but I don't find a way to get anything other than items from the first.

I need to be able to use indirection to a hidden value or hidden schema item, but haven't found out how yet.

```
def jsonEditorOptions = Boon.fromJson(/{
        disable_edit_json: true,
        disable_properties: true,
        no_additional_properties: true,
        disable_collapse: true,
        disable_array_add: true,
        disable_array_delete: true,
        disable_array_reorder: true,
        theme: "bootstrap2",
        iconlib:"fontawesome4",
"schema":
{
  "title": "Product",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "product", "branch" ],
  "properties": {
    "product": {
      "title": "Product",
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Product family being build",
      "default": "alpha",
      "enum": [ "alpha", "beta", "release"]
    },
    "branch" : {
      "title": "Branch",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "select",
      "watch": {
        "prod": "products"
      },
      "enumSource": "prod"
    }
  }
}, 
startval: { }
}/);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to use JSON Schema to retrieve an external list for your dropdown? If so, you cannot do this with JSON Schema, and I suggest you take a look at https://surveyjs.io

Comment: I don't want it to be an external list; I have the 3 lists at the same instant that I create the schema so I would rather they be part of the schema.

Comment: You can try using if / then / else, but it's unlikely that the library you're using supports draft-7. JSON Schema is not designed for creating forms, so anything beyond validation of a JSON instance is behaviour linked specifically to the library you are using. Can you provide a link to the specific library?

Comment: Thanks again - good point, I've edited the question to show the json library and explain that it is a Jenkins plugin.

Comment: The library only supports draft 3 and 4. There's nothing to suggest the library supports dynamic behaviour. Sorry. There is even an open issue where someone had a similar problem: https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor/issues/149 - It DOES look like the plugin page says you CAN do what you want, but doesn't tell you how... =/

Comment: My only suggestion here is to re-post your question, targeting those who know about the plugin, because this isn't something JSON Schema itself, or the library you linked to, can solve.